# Error when I try to save pandas as excel file in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I´m using the following code to get data from websocket and save as excel file, but when I try to open the file, the data is unorganized

```
import websocket
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['timestamp', 'symbol',  'side','size', 'price', 'tickDirection', 'trdMatchID', 'grossValue', 'homeNotional', 'foreignNotional'])

def on_open(ws):
    print("opened")

    auth_data = {
        'op': 'subscribe',
        'args': ['trade:XBTUSD']
    }
    ws.send(json.dumps(auth_data))

def on_message(ws, message):
    message = json.loads(message)
    print('\n',message)
    global df
    df = df.append(message, ignore_index=True)
    df.to_excel (r'D:\python\00trace.xlsx', header=True)
def on_close(ws):
    print("closed connection")

socket = "wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime"                 
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, 
                        on_open=on_open, 
                        on_message=on_message,
                        on_close=on_close)     
ws.run_forever()
```

and the excel that I get is:

[image]

Comment: Should you tag excel, as this seems to be an issue with other programs doing work prior to excel.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `message` does not have the same columns as your `df`. You probably need to cast the `message` JSON object into a DataFrame then rename the columns such that it matches the columns in `df`.